# VBA code to loop through different sheets and take specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone can share their knowledge and be of assistance.

I am trying to loop through DataSheet1, DataSheet2..... and take certain columns from each sheet.

I am sure this question has been asked before - my attempt at code is below.

I attempted to do it for one column but I got stuck in an infinite loop.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SummarySheet()

Dim WKSheetSummarySheet As Worksheet, WKSheetDataSheet1 As Worksheet, WKSheetDataSheet2 As Worksheet, WKSheetDataSheet3 As Worksheet, WKSheetDataSheet4 As Worksheet
Dim LastRowSummarySheet As Long, LastRowDataSheet1 As Long, LastRowDataSheet2 As Long, LastRowDataSheet3 As Long, LastRowDataSheet4 As Long
Dim LastColSummarySheet As Long, LastColDataSheet1 As Long, LastColDataSheet2 As Long, LastColDataSheet3 As Long, LastColDataSheet4 As Long
Dim RangeSummarySheet As Range, RangeDataSheet1 As Range, RangeDataSheet2 As Range, RangeDataSheet3 As Range, RangeDataSheet4 As Range

Set WKSheetSummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet")
Set WKSheetDataSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet1")
Set WKSheetDataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet2")
Set WKSheetDataSheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet3")
Set WKSheetDataSheet4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet4")

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
End With

On Error Resume Next

LastRowSummarySheet = WKSheetSummarySheet.Cells(WKSheetSummarySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowDataSheet1 = WKSheetDataSheet1.Cells(WKSheetDataSheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowDataSheet2 = WKSheetDataSheet2.Cells(WKSheetDataSheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowDataSheet3 = WKSheetDataSheet3.Cells(WKSheetDataSheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowDataSheet4 = WKSheetDataSheet4.Cells(WKSheetDataSheet4.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColSummarySheet = WKSheetSummarySheet.Cells(1, WKSheetSummarySheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColDataSheet1 = WKSheetDataSheet1.Cells(1, WKSheetDataSheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColDataSheet2 = WKSheetDataSheet2.Cells(1, WKSheetDataSheet2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColDataSheet3 = WKSheetDataSheet3.Cells(1, WKSheetDataSheet3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColDataSheet4 = WKSheetDataSheet4.Cells(1, WKSheetDataSheet4.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set RangeSummarySheet = Range(RangeSummarySheet.Cells(3, 2), RangeSummarySheet.Cells(LastRowSummarySheet, LastColSummarySheet))
Set RangeDataSheet1 = Range(RangeDataSheet1.Cells(5, 1), RangeDataSheet1.Cells(LastRowDataSheet1, LastColDataSheet1))
Set RangeDataSheet2 = Range(RangeDataSheet2.Cells(5, 1), RangeDataSheet2.Cells(LastRowDataSheet2, LastColDataSheet2))
Set RangeDataSheet3 = Range(RangeDataSheet3.Cells(5, 1), RangeDataSheet3.Cells(LastRowDataSheet3, LastColDataSheet3))
Set RangeDataSheet4 = Range(RangeDataSheet4.Cells(5, 1), RangeDataSheet4.Cells(LastRowDataSheet4, LastColDataSheet4))

Do Until IsEmpty(RangeDataSheet1(1))
    
    RangeDataSheet1(1) = RangeSummarySheet(1)
           
    Set RangeDataSheet1 = RangeDataSheet1.Offset(1, 0)
    Set RangeSummarySheet = RangeSummarySheet.Offset(1, 0)
    
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: I'd start by commenting out `On Error Resume Next` which hides errors and then you can see what's going on. Personally I steer clear of long variable names as I think it makes code hard to read. This is a personal preference but I cannot see the need for e.g. `WKSheetSummarySheet`.

Comment: `With` statements can also help to tidy up code as you avoid repetition. Btw I can't see that your code actually does anything except define ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm obviously missing a trick. What I want to do is go through each sheet and take the columns i want and append them to the Summary sheet. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well I put some in my first comment. You probably need to copy and paste.

Comment: I’m very new to vba. I have followed your instructions but I’m still at a loss. I could arguably record a macro but I am trying to learn some vba. I heard these forums are a great place to learn from experts. Thanks John.

Comment: Is there a particular algorithm or function for copying and pasting different columns in vba? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to decipher what you wanted to accomplish; if this code is not correct please clarify what you are trying to accomplish and provide and example of the data. This basic code below will loop through your four DataSheets copy the range from "A5" to the lastrow and lastcolumn, and then paste in the SummarySheet into the next empty row for each loop. Comments are added in the code.

*Side note*: when using the 'Equals' method, the source and destination range must be the same.

```
Sub ConsolidateSheetDataInSumSheet()
'This code will copy the range starting at "A5" to the lastrow and lastcolumn from each `DataSheet`,
'and paste to the next empty cell in `Column 2` in the 'SummarySheet'

Dim wsSum As Worksheet: Set wsSum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummarySheet") 'Define the SummmarySheet variable

    For x = 1 To 4 'Loop from 1 to 4 (the number for each datasheet)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet" & x) 'DataSheet1, DataSheet2, etc.

            'The next line sets the range from for each `DataSheet`, copies the range and 
            'pastes the copied range to the next empty cell in the `SummarySheet`
            'the line is separated using the Dash, `_`, for ease of reading

            .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy _
            wsSum.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    Next x 'Go to next `DataSheet`
End Sub
```

Comment: @John `I may need` does not clarify what you need, you need to be specific, what columns from each sheet do you want to copy?. Also, how do you want to consolidate the columns from each sheet on the summary sheet? Each group of columns below the other or side-by-side?.